# How do I host a django and a non-django site on my local development server?

Tags: django, apache

I have apache set up on my local machine to serve some django projects.  I am trying to develop another site that is not a django site.  When I try to look at the non-django site, apache tries to interpret its url through django, and gives an error that the url does not match any patterns in urls.py.

I can see the non-django site by commenting out the django-specific parts of httpd.conf and restarting apache.  But I know there is a way to tell apache not to try to interpret certain urls through django, or to only interpret certain urls through django.

I think the relevant parts of my setup are:

- All django projects are in /srv/python-environments/env_name/django_project_name
- All non-django sites are in /var/www/site_name
- The non-django sites consist of static html files, a wordpress blog, and a few simple (non-django) python scripts.
- I think I have set up all localhost urls to be interpreted as django urls through this line in httpd.conf, but I can't figure out how to change it:

  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/python-environments/phs_comp_env/phs_competencies/apache/django.wsgi
- I am running ubuntu 10.04, apache 2.2, django through mod_wsgi.

What do I need to change, or what other information do I need to provide?

For the record, this is what worked. I placed the non-django site configuration before the django site configuration:

```
Alias /non-django_site/ /var/www/non-django_site/
<Directory /var/www/non-django_site>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide enough information about the other non Python web application. One can only guess you are talking about PHP. Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Use the AddHandler method of mapping WSGI application and especially the solution towards the end of that section of the documentation.

Comment: I ended up placing the directives for the non-django sites first in httpd.conf, and used Alias settings for the non-django sites.

Your question about php helped my searching, even though I am not using php.  Rather than search something like "apache host django and non-django" I searched "apache host django and php", and "apache host multiple django sites".  These searches led to much more useful resources than I was finding.  Thank you for the lead.